# Azure's Swap functionality for staged publishing not working

Tags: azure, deployment

I'm trying to set up a staging environment for my application in Azure, following these instructions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing

I have my staging deployment slot set up and I deployed a change to it. I then tried hitting Swap to push the change to production.

The changes went to production just fine. But the old version that was previously on production went down to stage. It essentially "swapped" the sites. Which I know makes me sound crazy, given the Swap button, but I assumed it worked more like a Push...

Am I doing this wrong? The article makes it seem like it's a simple push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swap funcionality does indeed that, it swaps what's in your selected slot to Production (or other slot) and what's in your destination slot to the origin slot.

When the article mentions the **Push** it means that, when you Push to your code *repository* (implementing [Continuous Integration](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2015/11/25/automating-deployment-on-azure-web-apps.aspx)) it will Auto-Swap between your Staging and your Production, so you don't have to do it manually in the portal.

Internally, each slot has it's own storage space, so, what it's (putting it very simply) doing is swapping which storage space is each slot using.

Comment: Thanks @Matias - so say I've swapped my stage and production environments. Stage now has the old version1 site, and production has version2. If I make a version3 change in my repository, that gets pushed to stage, I can just swap again to put v3 on prod, and v2 will then be on stage...is that correct? I just want to make sure when I do future changes, they don't get overwritten between environments.

Comment: Thats correct. On code Push V3 goes to Staging, V2 is in Production, when Auto-Swap or Manual Swap gets fired, V3 goes to Production, V2 to Staging. That way, if you get a problem with V3 in production, you can swap back to the previous version.

Comment: Does it stay swapped until I deploy again? Or does it eventually sync up with production? It just seems strange to have an old version stay forever on the staging environment.

Comment: It depends. If you configure Auto-Swap, it swaps automatically when you Push code, the goal is to always have the latest code in Production with the Staging fallback to the previous version just in case. If you don't configure Auto-Swap, it stays swapped until you manually Swap.